# How can I programmatically checkin code in TFS with policy override?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I'm trying to checkin code from a c# program in a part of TFS repository which will trigger a gated checkin build and also a continuous integration build.
This is my code so far:

```
    public static void Checkin(string path, string comment)
    {
        var wsInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(path);
        var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(wsInfo.ServerUri);
        tfs.Connect(ConnectOptions.None);   

        var vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
        var ws = vcs.GetWorkspace(path);

        var fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(path);
        var change = ws.GetPendingChangesEnumerable().Where(p => p.LocalItem == fullPath).ToArray();

        ws.CheckIn(change.ToArray(), comment);

        tfs.Dispose();
    }
```

what is basically happening is that I get a GatedCheckinException say that there is an affected build defintion.
I would like to do the checkin with the commonly known bypass to avoid triggering the gated checkin. I've been struggling with the altenate Checkin functions without success.

Any idea?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks Aghilas Yakoub for the link.
For completeness, here is the code to do the checkin with override that worked for me:

```
var wip = new WorkspaceCheckInParameters(change, comment)
{
    OverrideGatedCheckIn = ((CheckInOptions2)vcs.SupportedFeatures & CheckInOptions2.OverrideGatedCheckIn) == CheckInOptions2.OverrideGatedCheckIn,
    PolicyOverride = new PolicyOverrideInfo("Check-in from the build.", null)
};

ws.CheckIn(wip);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you this sample of code http://blogs.infosupport.com/override-gated-check-in-using-the-tfs-api/

Comment: How MAX length (limit) for property **string Comment** ?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspacecheckinparameters.comment(v=vs.110).aspx